# Ws-security properties are not set when the outprops object is passed to it

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

I am trying to use cxf to connect to a server and am able to do it through SOAP ui but am getting errors when trying to connect through a java program I am writing.

```
  String WSU_NS     = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd";
String SOAP_NS    = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope";
String WSS_EXT_NS = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd";

                                            String uri = "someURI";
                                            String serviceName = "someServiceName";
                                            String urlWSDL = "someUrlWsdl";

        QName PORT_NAME   = new QName(uri, serviceName);
        URL url = new URL(urlWSDL);
        AdminService service = new AdminService(url, PORT_NAME);
        AdministrationSEI port = service.getAdminServicePort();
        Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);

        Map<String, Object> outProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, "Timestamp Signature");
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, "someusername");
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_PROP_FILE, "resources/clientKeyStore.properties");
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_KEY_ID, "DirectReference");
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS, "com.java.UTPasswordCallback");
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE_PARTS,
                          "{Content}{" + WSU_NS + "}Timestamp;"
                        + "{Content}{" + SOAP_NS + "}Body;"
                        + "{Content}{" + WSS_EXT_NS + "}BinarySecurityToken;");

        WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps);

        client.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);

        HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
        HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
        httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(30000);
        httpClientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout(7200000);
        http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);

        GetStatusType test = new GetStatusType();
        test.setRequestID(requestID);

        GetStatusResponseType response = port.getStatus(test);
```

What am I doing wrong? I have seen many examples where the outProps is added to the client in this way.

I have tried setting the user name directly in the client and it gets me past the error but the soap envelope is not being created correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing up the "manual" way of configuring WS-Security in CXF - by adding the WSS4JOutInterceptor, with the policy driven approach. The latter applies when you have a WS-SecurityPolicy in the WSDL - this is the case here, as the stacktrace references the PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor, which is added automatically. So for the policy approach, you don't add any interceptor, but instead add some JAX-WS properties that are required to configure the security runtime. See here for more information:

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-securitypolicy.html

Colm.

Comment: We prefer to run the "manual" way of ws-security. Is there an interceptor other than the WSS4JOutInterceptor that will work with out client object?

Comment: If you prefer the manual way, then you will have to work with a WSDL with no security policies.